# How do I create a functional function that creates a sdl window and renderer (when a sdl window and renderer is passed as arguments)?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I have **recently started** learning the C programming language and the SDL game development library. My objective with these two is to create several 2D games before graduating to something higher. In **attempting** my first game engine, I ran into no problem whatsoever because it was that basic; it consisted only of initializing SDL, loading surfaces and textures, and using keyboard events to control the positions of these textures onscreen.
Now, in creating my second game engine I am not so lucky and have run into *a problem* - which is why I am here. The problem stems from a **very basic** function that, when two arguments - a SDL window and renderer - are passed, creates a window along with a renderer. The function doesn't do its job!

With several google searches, I found out that the underlying cause of my function not working as it should was pointers. Though I have tried the proposed solutions, none managed to fix my problem.

**My first program (before research) is as below:**

Init Function

```
void setupSDL(SDL_Window *gameWin, SDL_Renderer *gameRen)
{

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
{
 printf("Initialization of SDL failed \t Error: %s \n",
 SDL_GetError() );
}




*gameWin = SDL_CreateWindow("pointerDebug",
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                            640,
                            480,
                            0);

if (!gameWin)
{
    printf("Failed to create window \t Error: %s \n", SDL_GetError() );
}


*gameRen = SDL_CreateRenderer(*gameWin, -1, 0);


if(!gameRen)
{
    printf("Failed to create renderer \t Error: %s \n", SDL_GetError() );

} 


}
```

Main Function

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


SDL_Window *gameWin;
SDL_Renderer *gameRen;


setupSDL(gameWin, gameRen);


//testing renderer 
SDL_RenderClear(gameRen);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gameRen, 0, 255, 0, 0);
SDL_RenderPresent(gameRen);


SDL_Delay(1000);

}
```

*This piece of code compiled with no error but unfortunately, when run, the renderer did not draw green to the window, as it should have done.*

**My second program (after research) is as below:**

Init Function

```
void setupSDL(SDL_Window **gameWin, SDL_Renderer **gameRen)
{
....
}
```

Main Function

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


SDL_Window *gameWin;
SDL_Renderer *gameRen;

setupSDL(&gameWin, &gameRen);

....

}
```

*After my online help on pointers, I tried the above code and still yielded the same results.*

Comment: Must read [Beginning Game Programming](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/) (for C - SDL1) and [Beginning Game Programming v2.0](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/) (for C++ - SDL2). They will get you there in no time. (the source code for all tutorials is available on the site) Start at the beginning (no cheating)

Comment: your second is approach,see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.SDL_Window.SDL_Renderer are struct if you want pass struct need using pointer;**

And you want create struct in function and pass it back you need pointer's pointer like below

---

**2.In your code**

SDL_RenderClear(gameRen);

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gameRen, 0, 255, 0, 0);

correct order is

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gameRen, 0, 255, 0, 0);

SDL_RenderClear(gameRen);

---

**3.sdl-2 using c++ i though,but anyway you can change my code "malloc" to "new","free" to "delete"**

---

**function give ini value :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
typedef struct SDL_Window SDL_Window;
typedef struct SDL_Renderer SDL_Renderer;

void setupSDL(SDL_Window **gameWinS, SDL_Renderer **gameRenS)
{
SDL_Window *gameWin; 
SDL_Renderer *gameRen;


if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
{
 printf("Initialization of SDL failed \t Error: %s \n",
 SDL_GetError() );
}




gameWin = SDL_CreateWindow("pointerDebug",
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                            640,
                            480,
                            0);

if (!gameWin)
{
    printf("Failed to create window \t Error: %s \n", SDL_GetError() );
}


gameRen = SDL_CreateRenderer(gameWin, -1, 0);


if(!gameRen)
{
    printf("Failed to create renderer \t Error: %s \n", SDL_GetError() );

} 
*gameWinS=gameWin;
*gameRenS=gameRen;

}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


SDL_Window **gameWin=(SDL_Window **)malloc(sizeof(SDL_Window *));
SDL_Renderer **gameRen=(SDL_Renderer **)malloc(sizeof(SDL_Renderer *));


setupSDL(gameWin, gameRen);


//testing renderer 

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(*gameRen, 0, 255, 0, 0);
SDL_RenderClear(*gameRen);
SDL_RenderPresent(*gameRen);


SDL_Delay(5000);
SDL_Quit();
free(gameWin);
free(gameRen);

return 0;
}
```

---

**give ini value in main :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
typedef struct SDL_Window SDL_Window;
typedef struct SDL_Renderer SDL_Renderer;




int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


SDL_Window *gameWin=NULL;
SDL_Renderer *gameRen=NULL;


if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
{
 printf("Initialization of SDL failed \t Error: %s \n",
 SDL_GetError() );
}




gameWin = SDL_CreateWindow("pointerDebug",
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                            640,
                            480,
                            0);

if (!gameWin)
{
    printf("Failed to create window \t Error: %s \n", SDL_GetError() );
}


gameRen = SDL_CreateRenderer(gameWin, -1, 0);


if(!gameRen)
{
    printf("Failed to create renderer \t Error: %s \n", SDL_GetError() );

}


//testing renderer 

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gameRen, 0, 255, 0, 0);
SDL_RenderClear(gameRen);
SDL_RenderPresent(gameRen);


SDL_Delay(5000);
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

---

compile in g++ with

-I/usr/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL2

---

**In your code**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


SDL_Window *gameWin;
SDL_Renderer *gameRen;

setupSDL(&gameWin, &gameRen);

....

}
```

SDL_Window *gameWin;

mean gameWin have unsure value or 0

then &gameWin is illegal

so you need malloc SDL_Window **gameWin; like my example

---

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

If you have some question you can send me message,i am free this month.

Comment: For what reason did you declare the typedef struct?

Comment: in sdl-1 not declare but in sdl-2 dont need that,i forget delete two line of them

Comment: typedef struct X X; make next declare dont need struct X variable-name;only need X  variable-name; example:struct SDL_Window *gameWin=NULL; only need SDL_Window *gameWin=NULL;

Comment: like declare next time i will call a person the first name mean is which one